# Before_widget won't show up

Tags: widgets, sidebar

EDIT: For those who are interested as per  Tom J Nowell the problem was that I used it with my own custom widget which doesn't have before and after support.

I have this sidebar and everything works fine except that the before and after widget don't show up:

```
register_sidebar( 
    array(
    'name'          => 'Footer Three',
    'id'            => 'footer-three',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="footer-three-wrapper">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    ) 
);
```

And inside page:

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-three' ); ?>
```

Isn't before_widget and after_widget supposed to show up?

Comment: In theory yes, but have you tested this with a standard widget? The Widget is responsible for outputting it, and if you forget to do that then it doesn't show

Comment: OK I got it. I used it with my custom widget and I hadn't bothered to include before and after. Thanks. Is there a way I mark it as Answer?

Comment: please make a proper answer from your edit and accept it

Comment: Answering your own question lets us vote it up and give you rep :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tom J Nowell I found out that the reason for **after_widget** and **before_widget** NOT appearing was that I used my own widget and inside my own widget I had commented out:

```
        //echo $args['before_widget'];
```

and

```
        //echo $args['after_widget'];
```

So as soon as I tested it with the default wordpress "Custom HTML" everything worked fine and **before_widget** and **after_widget** appeard as expected.